# Text on top of image using html/css

Tags: css, html, image, text

Hi I am new to HTML/CSS and I really need help I have already tried so many pieces of code but non of them seem to work at all. 
All I need is to put a text on top of an image situated on the bottom right. I already have the background picture set as I like it here's the code I have so far (nothing about the text yet):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Dream - Il Film</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <body>
        <style>            
            body {                
                background-image: url("THEDREAM.jpg");
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center !important;
                background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                filter:enter code hereprogid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.THEDREAM.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; 
            }
        </style>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi , you can put the image as background and put the text wherever you want using css. if you are looking for example let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image in a div and give appropriate padding to the image. Then you can type your text easily.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <p> TYPE TEXT HERE </p><br />
    <img style="padding-top:30px;width:50px;height:50px;">
</div>
```

U can change the values for styling.